# How to set working directory for application called from bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a bash script to execute an application. But, the application needs files stored in a particular directory. If I use `systemd` then I can use `WorkingDirectory` setting to define on which directory the service will be launched. But I am not sure how this can be done within bash script. Can anyone please let me know  how to achieve this?

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE="test"

if pgrep -x "$SERVICE" >/dev/null
    then
        echo "$SERVICE is running"
    else
        echo "starting $SERVICE"
        # The application "test" uses files stored in dir /home/example/ 
        /usr/bin/test
        exit 0
fi
```

Is doing `cd /home/example/` before executing the application enough?

Comment: Have you actually tried to do this? That would give you the information on whether it does or doesn't work. If it doesn't work, then you can edit the question and add error messages, what happened, what is supposed to happen, etc.

Comment: short answer is **yes** `cd /home/example` at start of script should be enough. just taste it ! (sorry can't resist the pun)